# How to forward a local USB camera over network with remote linux server?

Tags: python, linux

Let's say I have an Ubuntu laptop with several USB ports. I also have a remote VM that's running Ubuntu/Apache2.

How do I forward/stream my USB camera's RTSP feed over the remote server effectively turning:

Local webcam IP: 192.168.1.1 (example)

into

Remote Webcam IP: 129.313.411 (example)